# WCF OperationContract With Parameters Of Type Object

Tags: c#, wcf

I am hosting WCF service in my Windows application with service and data contracts

```
[ServiceContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(object))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(busSample))]
public interface IUPSBusinessTier
{

    [OperationContract]
    string TestMethod1(string astrName);

    [OperationContract]
    void TestMethod2(busSample abusSample);

    [OperationContract]
    busSample TestMethod3(string astrName);

    [OperationContract]
    string TestMethod4(object astrName);
}

[DataContract]
public class busSample 
{

    [DataMember]
    public string istrName { get; set; }

    public busSample()
    {

        this.istrName = "ABC";
    }
}
```

While testing service using WCFTestClient, getting error like "The deserializer has no knowledge of which type to deserialize. Check that the type being serialized has the same contract as the enter code here type being deserialized."

Comment: What method are you getting the error on?

Comment: Where do you get that error?

Answer (score 0):

I think you just need to move the fault contract attribute from the class onto the methods.

```
   [ServiceContract]
//[FaultContract(typeof(object))]
[ServiceKnownType(typeof(busSample))]
public interface IUPSBusinessTier
{
    [FaultContract(typeof(object))]
    [OperationContract]
    string TestMethod1(string astrName);

    [FaultContract(typeof(object))]
    [OperationContract]
    void TestMethod2(busSample abusSample);
```